# Does this Android permission prevent me from getting error reports?

Tags: android, air

In my application descriptor file there is this line:

```
<!--Removing the permission android.permission.INTERNET will have the side effect
                of preventing you from debugging your application on your device-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Does this mean I won't be able to debug my application with Flash Builder or does it mean that if my app crashes as a user is running it I won't get error reports in Google App developer center?

Answer (score 1):

Nope and No! This is just a permission it wouldn't affect any of the above. It just allows your application to connect to Internet.

But maybe your application needs Internet just to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

ANR and Crash reporting is integrated into OS, and handled via Play Store services. It has nothing to do with your App's permissions.